# Rust serde untagged enum fails

Tags: rust, enums, deserialization, serde

I'm tying to deserialize one of two structs using serde. The input comes from a csv file.

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::io;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct A {
    value: i8,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct B {
    value: String,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum C {
    One(A),
    Two(B),
}

fn main() {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(io::stdin());
    for result in rdr.deserialize() {
        let record: Result<C, csv::Error> = result;
        match record {
            Ok(value) => {
                println!("ok");
            }
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Error parsing line: {}", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand untagged enums correctly, this should try parsing it as an A struct, so just an i8, if that fails, try parsing it as a B struct, so just a String.

I've verified that my structs deserialize correctly on their own.

Here's the command I run:

```bash
echo "value\nTest\n1" | cargo r
```

Here's the output:

```
Error parsing line: CSV deserialize error: record 1 (line: 2, byte: 6): data did not match any variant of untagged enum C
Error parsing line: CSV deserialize error: record 2 (line: 3, byte: 11): data did not match any variant of untagged enum C
```

Comment: If you tag `A` and `B` as `serde(transparent)` does it work?

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues It does, however in my actual code I have more than one field in the structs, if I understand `#[serde(transparent)]` correctly, it's not applicable in that case.

Comment: The underlying problem is that, at least in this case, the deserializer is expecting either a `A("value")` or `B(1)` value when deserializing, but it's finding `"value"`, which doesn't match either case.
This isn't specific to untagged enums, I believe, a tagged enum would also not allow parsing `A("value")` from `"value"`, only with `serde(transparent)`.
If you can't tag the enums as such, you will likely need some custom deserializer to construct your `A` and `B` from the data given.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues I just tried it using serde_json, and it worked just as I would expect. Maybe the problem is more with csv?

Answer (score 1):

If you switch your model from "`enum` of `structs`" to "`struct` containing `enum`", the `csv` input works as expected:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum Value {
    One(i8),
    Two(String),
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    value: Value,
}

fn main() {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(io::stdin());
    for result in rdr.deserialize() {
        let record: Result<Data, csv::Error> = result;
        match record {
            Ok(value) => {
                println!("ok");
            }
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Error parsing line: {}", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the `csv` crate isn't able to understand that the `value` field in your `struct` `A` and the `value` field in your `struct` `B` should belong to the same column. Since they have the same name, defining as a `struct` containing an untagged `enum` makes more sense.